# I would like to convert an int to string in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to convert a column in dataframe to a string 
it looks like this :

```
company department  id  family  name    start_date  end_date
abc sales   38221925    Levy    nali    16/05/2017  01/01/2018
```

I want to convert the id from int to string

I tried

```
data['id']=data['id'].to_string()
```

and

```
data['id']=data['id'].astype(str)
```

got dtype('O')

I expect to receive string

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour. This is how pandas stores strings.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes)

> Pandas uses the object dtype for storing strings.

For a simple test, you can make a dummy dataframe and check it's dtype too.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["abc", "ab"])
df[0].dtype
#Output:
dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using apply() function in this way: 
 
`data['id'] = data['id'].apply(lambda x: str(x))` 

This will convert all the values of **id** column to string. 
You can ensure the type of the values like this: 
`type(data['id'][0])` (It is checking the first value of 'id' column)
 
This will give the output `str`.
 
And `data['id'].dtype` will give `dtype('O')` that is object.

You can also use `data.info()` to check all the information about that DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
str(12)

>>'12'
```

Can easily convert to a String